# DataGridView - Somar Se (Sum If)

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Estou criando um software em VB para analisar o balanceamento de postos de trabalho em fabricas. O software possui um DataGridView da seguinte forma:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu preciso criar um gráfico de barras empilhadas (Stacked Bar) por posto (cada barra sendo um posto) e atividades distinguidas em cada barra (cada trecho de cor diferente corresponde a uma atividade dentro daquele posto) conforme a figura abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu não tenho muita experiência com a lógica envolvida, mas sei que é possível fazer este tipo de gráfico rapidamente utilizando Gráfico Dinâmico no Excel.

Gostaria de pedir orientações de como ler os dados linha a linha do DataGridView, agrupá-los corretamente e em que tipo de variável, para que possa passá-los como argumentos corretamente para o controle Chart no Visual Basic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Há várias maneiras de fazer isso, contudo sua pergunta não deixa muito claros alguns detalhes, por exemplo como o seu DataGridView é povoado. Ele está vinculado a alguma fonte de dados, por exemplo, um DataTable ou DataView? Ou você está recuperando essas informações e preenchendo diretamente cada DataGridViewRow? Acredito que sua melhor opção seja partir desses dados e preparar objetos contendo os filtros e consultas que lhe interessem, e com base neles definir os parâmetros de exibição do Chart. Agora para dizer como exatamente fazer isso dependeria de analisar diretamente o código e os dados que você está utilizando. Não sei se lhe ajuda, mas localizei um tutorial sobre Chart em português: http://www.macoratti.net/10/09/vbn_graf.htm